# Parsing select statement with regex (for custom SQL parser)

Tags: sql, regex, parsing

I am doing this for didactic purposes (building a teaching database; building parts of it just as full-blown databases have it; this is for a very simple query parser.)

I am trying to parse out simple "select" statement using regex. It works for most simple cases, but I am losing it at the balance of allowing spaces between selection of tables (*from a,b;*), allowing unlimited spaces between from and terminator *;*, and allowing for optional restrictor "*where*" and unlimited spaces between *from a,b where* and *;*

Here is the regex:

```
select\s(.*)\sfrom(.*)\s(where (.*))?\s;
```

and here are sample queries:

```
select a.a,b.b,c from a,b where a.a = b.a;

select a.a,b.b,c from a,b;

select a.a,b.b,c from a,b ;

select a.a,b.b,c from a,b where a.a = b.a  ;
```

Available on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/bBFgrO/3) with unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for the examples provided : `select\s+(.*?)\s*from\s+(.*?)\s*(where\s(.*?)\s*)?;`

See here : https://regex101.com/r/sBwpok/3

Answer (score 2):

The regex `select\s+(.*)\s+from\s+(.*)\s*(where .*)?;` passed all the tests. The only modification I added is `\s+` rather than a single space `\s`