# getting metadata from a query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, metadata

I need to extract column level informations from a query(or sp) like below.

Sample Query

```
  select a.Col1 ,b.col2 ,case when a.col3 = 'abc' then b.col4 else a.col5 end 
  from tablea A
  join tableb B on a.col6 = b.col7
  where a.col8 = '123'
```

output needed :

```
Tables  Column  usage
TableA  Col1    select
TableB  Col2    select
TableA  Col3    select
TableB  Col4    select
TableA  Col5    select
TableA  Col6    Join
TableB  Col7    join
TableA  Col8    where
```

Comment: You're looking for a SQL Parser. I've never come across one. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015852/parsing-select-statement-with-regex-for-custom-sql-parser What tool do you want to use to extract this info?

Comment: SHOWPLAN XML _might_ contain the information you're looking for.